# nested user-specific forms in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm attempting to build a nested form for my Devise users to fill out and then later update. The form consists of two models; one for questions and another for users.  My controller looks like this:

```
class LegalFormsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_legal_form, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :answers]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @legal_forms = LegalForm.all
    respond_with(@legal_forms)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@legal_form)
  end

  def new
    @legal_form = LegalForm.new
    respond_with(@legal_form)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @legal_form = LegalForm.new(legal_form_params)
    @legal_form.save
    respond_with(@legal_form)
  end

  def update
    @legal_form.update(legal_form_params)
    respond_with(@legal_form)
  end

  def destroy
    @legal_form.destroy
    respond_with(@legal_form)
  end

  def answers
    @users = User.all
    @questions = @legal_form.questions
  end

  private

  def set_legal_form
    @legal_form = LegalForm.find(params[:id])
  end

  def legal_form_params
    params.require(:legal_form).permit(:name,
                    :questions_attributes => [:id, :content,
                                  :answers_attributes =>[:id, :content, :participant_id]
                                ])
  end
end
```

and the view for the answers is (currently) as follows:

```
<h1><%= @legal_form.name %> Answers</h1>

<%= form_for(@legal_form) do |f| %>
  <% @users.each do |user| -%>
  <h3><%= user.id %></h3>
  <table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Questions</td>
    <td>Answer</td>
  </tr>
<tbody>
  <% @questions.each do |question| -%>
    <tr>
      <td><%= question.content %></td>
      <td>
    <%= f.fields_for :questions, question do |q| -%>
      <%=q.fields_for :answers, question.answers.find_or_initialize_by(user: @user) do |a| -%>
        <%= a.text_area :content %>
        <%= a.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user %>
      <% end -%>
    <% end -%>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <% end -%>
  </tbody>
</table>
  <% end -%>
  <div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end =%>
```

As you can see, this currently brings up all questions/answers for all users.
My question is two-fold:

1. How might I set this up to just bring up the current user?
2. Using this line `<%= a.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user %>`, I am attempting to provide the current user id for each answer saved to the answers database under user_id.  However, it doesn't seem to be working.  What might I be missing?

Many thanks for any help on this!

**As requested, below are my model associations**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end

class LegalForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :questions

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
    :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :answers
  has_many :questions, through: :answers
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :legal_form
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, through: :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set user_id value like this

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  I've included my model associations above.

Comment: Thank you for your appreciation